# Erro de consulta em banco de dados - número inválido

Tags: sql, oracle

Boa tarde. Estou com problema em uma consulta em banco de dados. Ao realizá-la, retorna esse erro:

```
ORA-01722: número inválido
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Meu código:

```
SELECT T2.ID_EMPRESA, T2.ID_EQUIPAMENTO, T1.ID_OBRA, T1.ID_ATIVIDADE, SUM(T1.KM_FINAL - T1.KM_INICIAL) AS DIFERENCA_KMS
FROM CE_REGISTRO_LEVES T1
INNER JOIN CE_BOLETIM T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID_BOLETIM AND T2.DATA BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/06/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('30/06/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
WHERE CASE WHEN T1.ID_OBRA = '82' AND T1.ID_ATIVIDADE = '12' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = 1
GROUP BY T2.ID_EMPRESA, T2.ID_EQUIPAMENTO, T1.ID_OBRA, T1.ID_ATIVIDADE
ORDER BY T2.ID_EQUIPAMENTO
```

Alguém consegue me auxiliar? Obrigado.

Comment: Você tem certeza que KM_FINAL e KM_INICIAL sao campos numéricos? Eu creio que seja ai o problema.

Comment: Seria mais fácil responder sua pergunta de forma mais certeira se você informar como são modeladas as tabelas `CE_REGISTRO_LEVES` e `CE_BOLETIM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fazer `JOIN` com `BETWEEN` não é boa ideia. É melhor mover o `BETWEEN` para o `WHERE`. O seu `CASE` também parece ser algo mais complicado do que deveria ser, podendo ser simplificado. Sugiro fazer isso:

```
SELECT
    T2.ID_EMPRESA,
    T2.ID_EQUIPAMENTO,
    T1.ID_OBRA,
    T1.ID_ATIVIDADE,
    SUM(T1.KM_FINAL - T1.KM_INICIAL) AS DIFERENCA_KMS
FROM
    CE_REGISTRO_LEVES T1
INNER JOIN CE_BOLETIM T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID_BOLETIM
WHERE T2.DATA BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/06/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    AND TO_DATE('30/06/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND (T1.ID_OBRA <> '82' OR T1.ID_ATIVIDADE <> '12')
GROUP BY T2.ID_EMPRESA, T2.ID_EQUIPAMENTO, T1.ID_OBRA, T1.ID_ATIVIDADE
ORDER BY T2.ID_EQUIPAMENTO
```